# Pass querystring parameters in AWS API Gateway iOS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-ios

I have set up an API Gateway for an AWS Lambda function. In the API Gateway I have setup the query string parameter and the request mapping. If I use the test function of the API Gateway I can pass the parameter to my AWS Lambda function.

I have also generated an SDK API for iOS using [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-console) instructions.

However, how can I pass my pre-defined query string parameter into this generated API class?

I have also tried using a model, however I do not see a way to pass the model data into the iOS SDK either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined your query parameters in your API "Method Request", the SDK should be generated with the query parameters as arguments to your invocation method.

i.e.

```
- (AWSTask *)rootGet:(NSString *)q2 q1:(NSString *)q1 {
    NSDictionary *headerParameters = @{
                                       @"Content-Type": @"application/json",
                                       @"Accept": @"application/json",

                                       };
    NSDictionary *queryParameters = @{
                                      @"q2": q2,
                                     @"q1": q1
                                      };
    NSDictionary *pathParameters = @{

                                     };

    return [self invokeHTTPRequest:@"GET"
                         URLString:@"/"
                    pathParameters:pathParameters
                   queryParameters:queryParameters
                  headerParameters:headerParameters
                              body:nil
                     responseClass:[FOOEmpty class]];
}
```

Keep in mind that if you make changes to your API, the changes will need to be re-deployed to your stage before you re-generate your SDK.